# PHP code not getting exact result as needed

Tags: php, mysql

Need a solution :

Problem with the PHP code result not getting exact results i need a solution

my result shows that the creation_date of every user is the same

Here is my Code

```
// Array of "created_by" user IDs from tbl_rsd_activity
$createdByUsers = ['KL031', 'KL046', 'KL035', 'KL036', 'KL038', 'KL040', 'KL039', 'KW095' ]; // Replace with the desired "created_by" user IDs

$queryCreated = "SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT l.id) as leadid_count, l.datecreated as datecreated
                 FROM tbl_rsd_leads l
                 GROUP BY datecreated
                 ORDER BY datecreated DESC";

$queryModified = "SELECT created_by, COUNT(DISTINCT a.leadid) as leadid_count, a.datemodified as datemodified
                  FROM tbl_rsd_activity a
                  WHERE a.status = 0 AND a.created_by IN ('" . implode("','", $createdByUsers) . "')
                  GROUP BY created_by, datemodified
                  ORDER BY datemodified DESC";



$resultCreated = $kwcomdb->query($queryCreated);
$resultModified = $kwcomdb->query($queryModified);

if ($resultCreated && $resultModified) {
    $countsCreated = $resultCreated->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $countsModified = $resultModified->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    // Organize results by date
    $leadCountsByDateCreated = array();
    $leadCountsByDateModified = array();

    foreach ($countsCreated as $count) {
        $dateCreated = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($count['datecreated']));
        $leadidCount = $count['leadid_count'];

        if (!isset($leadCountsByDateCreated[$dateCreated])) {
            $leadCountsByDateCreated[$dateCreated] = 0;
        }

        $leadCountsByDateCreated[$dateCreated] += $leadidCount;
    }

    foreach ($countsModified as $count) {
        $dateModified = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($count['datemodified']));
        $createdBy = $count['created_by'];
        $leadidCount = $count['leadid_count'];

        if (!isset($leadCountsByDateModified[$dateModified][$createdBy])) {
            $leadCountsByDateModified[$dateModified][$createdBy] = 0;
        }

        $leadCountsByDateModified[$dateModified][$createdBy] += $leadidCount;
    }

    // Display results in a table
    echo "<table class='table table-striped table-bordered table-hover' id='report'>";
    echo "<tr><th>Date</th>";

    // Create header row with "Created By" users
    foreach ($createdByUsers as $createdByUser) {
         if($createdByUser == 'KL031'){
             $createdByUser = 'Kulwinder Kaur';
         }elseif($createdByUser == 'KL046'){
             $createdByUser = 'Pradeep Kumar';
         }elseif($createdByUser == 'KL035'){
             $createdByUser = 'Loveleen Kaur';
         }elseif($createdByUser == 'KL036'){
             $createdByUser = 'Simran Kaur';
         }elseif($createdByUser == 'KL038'){
             $createdByUser = 'Sushil Kumar';
         }elseif($createdByUser == 'KL040'){
             $createdByUser = 'Neha Kashyap';
         }elseif($createdByUser == 'KL039'){
             $createdByUser = 'Aitka Kausin';
         }elseif($createdByUser == 'KW095'){
             $createdByUser = 'Nitin Sharma';
         }else{
             $createdByUser  = $createdByUser ;
         }
        echo "<th>$createdByUser</th>";
    }

    echo "</tr>";

    // Loop through dates and display lead counts for each "created_by" user in a single row
    
    $chk_count = 60;  // check loop count to show 100 records in table
    $loop_val=1;
    foreach ($leadCountsByDateCreated as $date => $totalLeadCountCreated) {
                    if($loop_val<= $chk_count){
          echo "<tr>";
                    $fdatemodified=date('jS F Y', strtotime($date));
                                                
                                        $is_saturday = date('N', strtotime($date));
                                        $is_sunday = date('N', strtotime($date));
                                                
                                                $weekend="";                                                
                                                if($is_saturday==6) { $weekend='Saturday'; } 
                                                if($is_sunday==7) { $weekend='Sunday'; } 
        echo "<td>$fdatemodified <span class='text-success'><b> ".$weekend." </b></span></td>";
        
    

        foreach ($createdByUsers as $createdByUser) {
            $totalLeadCountModified = isset($leadCountsByDateModified[$date][$createdByUser]) ? $leadCountsByDateModified[$date][$createdByUser] : 0;

            // Display the total count with a "+" sign
            echo "<td>$totalLeadCountCreated + $totalLeadCountModified</td>";
        }

        echo "</tr>";
            }
        $loop_val++;
    }

    echo "</table>";

    // Free result sets
    $resultCreated->closeCursor();
    $resultModified->closeCursor();
} else {
    echo "Error executing query: ". $kwcomdb->errorInfo()[2];
}
```

Here is the output which shows a count of $totalLeadCountCreated as the same for every user it should be different for each user

[Click to see the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ThBu3.jpg)

Comment: `$leadCountsByDateCreated` is not organized by user. There's just one value for each date.

Comment: So how could it be different for each user?

Comment: $totalLeadCountCreated showing same count for each user in col

Comment: I know. Because it's just the total count for each date, not specific to each user. `$leadCountsByDateModified` has different values for each user.

Comment: So how do we make a query or PHP code to show the result
each user has a lead_count from both tables?  how many from the created date and how many from the modified date in desc order

Comment: Unrelated, but instead of of using your display logic to limit what is shown, you should be using LIMIT and OFFSET in your queries. As-is, it pulls all the data, and then you potentially ignore some of it. It is better to just not query it at all if it won't be used.

Comment: You need to change `$queryCreated` to include the user in the output and grouping, so you can make a 2-dimensional array like `$leadCountsByDateModified`.

Comment: yes how we can adjust created_by